# ajv triggers user defined keyword only once

Tags: json, typescript, validation, ajv

I need to implement user defined keyword for `ajv` which will be triggered for every node which match the schema. In snippet below my user defined keyword is called `order`.

```
const schema = {
  $schema: "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
  $id: "http://www.cognitran.com/publication/service",
  type: "object",
  properties: {
    a: {
      $ref: "#/$defs/a",
    },
  },
  $defs: {
    a: {
      type: "array",
      order: [{ element: "b", minOccurs: "1" }, { element: "c" }],
      items: {
        b: {
          $ref: "#/$defs/d",
        },
      },
    },
    d: {
      type: "array",
      order: [{ element: "e", minOccurs: "1" }],
      items: {
        e: {
          type: "string",
        },
      },
    },
  },
};
```

My implementation of own keyword is pretty straightforward:

```
import { CodeKeywordDefinition, KeywordCxt } from "ajv";

export const orderCode = (): CodeKeywordDefinition => ({
  keyword: "order",
  code: (context: KeywordCxt): void => {
    try {
      const { schema, parentSchema, data } = context;
      console.log(schema, parentSchema, data);

      if (!data) {
        throw new Error("Order keyword probably used in incorrect node in schema.");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  },
});
```

When I used json object to validate against schema above, my breakpoint in user defined schema is executed once while validating object `a`, but it's not triggered when validated object node `d`. Validation which is executed only for the first node skipping nested nodes is useless.

```
const json = {
  a: [
    {
      b: [
        {
          d: [
            {
              e: "Hello",
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
};
```

Do you have any idea why user defined keyword is triggered only once? How to change configuration for `ajv` to trigger user defined keyword every time for all nodes when it matches with schema?

My configuration for adv looks like below:

```
const ajv = new Ajv2020({ allErrors: true, strict: false, verbose: true });
// Add custom keywords to extend JSON schema
const orderKeyword = orderCode(); // order code is my user defined keyword
ajv.addKeyword(orderKeyword);
```

Thank you for any suggestions.

Rafal